# Single dictionary initialization with different types of keys

Tags: c#

Has anyone used class initialization like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary {
    [address] = address,
    [person] = person,
    [biz] = biz
};
```

How do I declare such class `Dictionary` which initializes using above line,
Never used [] in dictionary initialization which takes different types as key

`address`, `person`, `biz` are objects off different classes Address, Person and Biz

reference: [problem I am solving](http://www.alliancereservations.com/programmer-test.html)

**Updates**

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public bool Save()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool Delete()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Address : BaseEntity
{
    public Address() { }

    public Address(string addressLine1, string addressLine2, string state, string zip)
    {
        this.AddressLine1 = addressLine1;
        this.AddressLine2 = addressLine2;
        this.State = state;
        this.ZipCode = zip;
    }

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public static Address Find(string id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Business : BaseEntity
{
    public Business() { }

    public Business(string businessName, Address address)
    {
        this.Name = businessName;
        this.Address = address;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public static Business Find(string id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    public Person() { }

    public Person(string fname, string lname, Address address)
    {
        this.FirstName = fname;
        this.LastName = lname;
        this.Address = address;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public static Person Find(string id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can if all those classes implements some base class or interface

Comment: the classes are inheriting from same base type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to consider:

```
// Some example data of different types
var address = "";
var person = new object();
var biz = new List<int>();

var dictionary = new Dictionary<object,object> { [address] = address, [person] = person, [biz] = biz };
```

Answer (score 3):

> Never used [] in dictionary initialization which takes different types as key

Index initializers are available since C# 6.0

```
new Dictionary<int, string> { [7] = "seven" };
```

This uses the indexer instead of the `Add` method so adding the same key multiple times will not throw exception but replaces the original instance.

And the support of different types can be achieved by using `object` for keys and values. The `Dictionary` type in the source must be something like this:

```
public class Dictionary : Dictionary<object, object> {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Dictionary needs to key on the type, it can be done thus:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Type, Object> {
    [typeof(Address)] = new Address(),
    [typeof(Person)] = new Person(),

    // If you have an existing object, then like this.
    [address.GetType()] = address
};
```

The code that reads the dictionary can then do something like:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, Object> kv in dict) {
    var castedObject = Convert.ChangeType(kv.Value, kv.Key);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Address, Person,Biz classes must implement common base class or interface say BaseX. The key shall be a string which is the name of the derived class. And:

```
var dictionary<string, BaseX> dict = new Dictionary<string, BaseX>();
dict.Add("address", new address());
dict.Add("person", new person());
dict.Add("biz", new biz());
```

Thanks